# how to add property to dynamic object while it is accessed in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic

i want to create a property into a dynamic Object, just before it is accessed.
for e.g let's say, there is an object X. a non existing property "SomeProperty" is accessed on X as follows,

```
var testProperty = X.SomeProperty;
```

i want to create X.SomeProperty, while it is accessed.
is it possible in C# dynamics?

Comment: If SomeProperty has not been set yet but is accessed what do you want it to return? An empty object? Null? 41?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class X : DynamicObject
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override bool TryGetMember(
        GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        string name = binder.Name.ToLower();

        return dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        dictionary[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;
        return true;
    }
}


dynamic obj = new X();
obj.SomeProperty = "Test";
Console.WriteLine(obj.SomeProperty);
```

Comment: When you try to assign a value to the property (e.g. `obj.SomeProperty = 5`), you'll get a `RuntimeBinderException`.

Comment: @NikolaAnusev your right i just added the full example I was just giving a quick and dirty example before. Thank you for pointing out